# autocomplete textfield CJuiAutoComplete widget yii storing the hidden field id and displaying name

Tags: autocomplete, yii

I am looking for auto-complete  to work by showing name in auto-complete text-field and storing the hidden field id value.

I am getting the names and id's when I inspect the networks..but able to show the names but its not picking the id for the record so unable to store the id

can anyone please give me any link/code which is working for auto-complete. is there any link/code which is working please..

class for auto-complete:::

```
class EAutoCompleteAction extends CAction{
public $model;
public $attribute;
public $id;
private $results = array();
public $returnVal = '';
public function run()
{
    if(isset($this->model) && isset($this->attribute)) {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->compare($this->attribute, $_GET['term'], true);
        $model = new $this->model;
        foreach($model->findAll($criteria) as $m)
        {
            $this->results[] = $m->{$this->attribute};
            $this->results[] = $m->{$this->id};
            //$this->results[] = array(
            //      'name' => $m->{$this->attribute},
            //      'id'=> $m->id
            //);


        }
    }

    echo CJSON::encode($this->results);
}
}
```

I am  using controller/action like this::

```
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'aclist'=>array(
            'class'=>'application.extensions.EAutoCompleteAction',
            'model'=>'Organisation', //My model's class name
            'attribute'=>'name', //The attribute of the model i will search


        )


}
```

and in my view form.php.

```
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'organsiation'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'organisation_id',array()); ?>
    <?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
'attribute'=>'organisation_id',
'model'=>$model,
'sourceUrl'=>array('benefit/aclist'),
'value'=>'Please select',
'name'=>'name',
'id'=>'organisation_id',
'options'=>array(
    'minLength'=>'2',
     'select'=>"js:function(event, ui) {
 alert(ui.item.id);
                                    $('#organisation_id').val(ui.item.id);
                                    }",
),
'htmlOptions'=>array(
'size'=>45,
'maxlength'=>45,
),
)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'organisation_id'); ?>
```

Comment: are you getting anything in alert(ui.item.id); ?? try to investigate the "ui" object in console.log.

Comment: no..im not getting any id either..but im getting the value and id when i checked in chrome inspector/networks/response..

Comment: so are you getting the "ui.item" object ?

Comment: And the response you are getting is JSON. right ?

Comment: yes..getting jason response. but i didnt understand ui.item. Itried with array respose as well by using name1|id1,name2|id2,name3|id3....... format. these value formats i'm getting in chrome/networks/response but its not cming up in textfield nt picking id too,.

Comment: if "#organisation_id"  is text field then you should try to do it like "input#organisation_id" ...

 $('input#organisation_id').val(ui.item.id);

Answer (score 2):

Here my code for autocomplete

1. Create an action that return json

   ```
   public function listaItemMarcaAction(){
       $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
       $cmd->select('id, nombre as value, nombre as label, pais_origen');
       $cmd->from('item_marca');
       $cmd->where('nombre like :term', array(':term'=>'%'.request()->getParam('term').'%'));
       $data = $cmd->queryAll();
       header('Content-type: application/json');
       echo CJavaScript::jsonEncode($data);
       Yii::app()->end();
   }
   ```
2. Create autocomplete field and hidden field (in view files, example _form.php)

   ```
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'marca_id'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'marca_id'); ?>
   <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
       'name'=>"Item[marca]",
       'value'=>$model->isNewRecord ? null : $model->marca->nombre,
       'sourceUrl'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/item/listaitemmarca'),
       'options'=>array(
           'minLength'=>1,
           'change'=>'js:function(event,ui){fn_item_data(event,ui)}'
       ),
   )); ?>
   ```
3. Create a javascript function to set values retreives by autocomplete. Nota that: only use change event, no need any more. In the example, the ActiveRecord is 'Item', then, the input's id wil be Item_marca_id and Item_marca.

   ```
   function fn_item_data(event,ui){
       if(!ui.item){
           $("#Item_marca_id").val("");
           $("#Item_marca").val("");
       }else{
           $("#Item_marca_id").val(ui.item.id);
           $("#Item_marca").val(ui.item.value);
           //and use ui.item.pais_origen for another things
           if(ui.item.pais_origen == 'EEUU') alert('ok');
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation I would start with plain JQuery instead of CJuiAutoComplete on the client side. JQuery UI docs have a nice demo with working source code at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data. There are three essential steps to get things working:

1. Supply data as array of JSON objects, not strings.
2. Use custom `_renderItem` function to render your JSON objects into readable strings.
3. Use custom `select` function to record visible `name` of selected JSON object into text field and record `id` of this object into hidden field.

To make step 1 you'll need to uncomment commented out part of EAutoCompleteAction, and remove two lines above it. After that you should be able to see item id and name in your `alert()` messages.

Step 2 (overriding `_renderItem`) is particularly tricky to do with CJuiAutoComplete, that is the reason I suggested to go with plain JQuery UI. See [the above link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) for the example with plain JQuery UI. An example with CJuiAutoComplete can be found in the comments section of Yii docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAutoComplete#c8376. After step 2 you should be able to see readable autocomplete suggestions.

To make step 3 you'll need to add something like

```
$('#organisation_name').val( ui.item.name );
```

into your `select` function, provided that `organisation_name` is the id of your text field and `organisation_id` is the id of hidden form field (you'll need some changes to make it so).